# i18n : localization of currency without passing locale ISO code

Tags: internationalization, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

i am using i18n for localization of currency

i do it easily by below code and it works fine

**component :**

```html
<i18n-n
  :value="Price"
  format="currency"
  :locale="currentLocale"
></i18n-n>
```

**But** i have to pass **current** **locale** `ISO` code to it then i need a **computed**
and this is **not** clean way .

**computed:**

```js
currentLocale() {
  const current_language = this.$i18n.locale
  return (this.$i18n as any).locales.find(
    (item: any) => item.code === current_language
  ).iso
}
```

i want to know if there is any way to force `i18n` to recognize **current locale** ISO code **internally**

Comment: Why don't you directly use `this.$i18n.locale` here?

Comment: because that gets locale code(en) not ISO (en-GB)

Comment: You could either configure it in the module somewhere I guess, otherwise set it as a global state in Vuex to have it globally in your app.